# Difference when ignoring files in folder with git

Tags: git

What is/are the difference(s) when writing this in .gitignore:

```
/tmp/*
/tmp
/tmp/
```

I noticed that if I create a folder `tmp`, no matter what I write in my `.gitignore` it does not appear when I do `git status`. What is the difference between those three, and what should I write if I want the folder to be commited, but not the files within it.

Comment: As I recall, git works on per-file basis and `clone` will not create empty directories. Would like to be proven wrong.

Comment: That is my understanding as well. Git does not track empty directories.

Comment: Interesting. So, if the directory is needed in a project, and I want other users to have it. What is the solution? I mean, I want to share the structure of my app, but not the files within that folder.

Comment: Add dummy file. `.gitignore` as shown in answer, or anything else that you wouldn't use. Or make your build system (if you use one, e.g. `make`) create these directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` does not track empty folders, thus if it thinks nothing is inside of it, it won't add it.  One solution to your problem would be instead of adding `/tmp/*` to your *global* `.gitignore` file, put one *into* the `/tmp/` folder, just containing

```
*
!.gitignore
```

and commit this file.  In this way, `/tmp/` won't be empty to `git` and thus be added to the repository, but no further files would be.